# F# Pattern Match JSON Type Provider or Class Type

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, f#-data

Is it possible to pattern match a `property` from a class type?

```ml
type A = JsonProvider<"""[{"name": "", "age": 1}]""">
let json = """[{"name": "Kitten", "age": 322}]"""
let a = A.Parse(json)

match a with
| {name=name} // <- The record label 'name' is not defined.
```

Comment: That matching syntax only works for records, and `JsonProvider` doesn't create records. Consider an active pattern.

Comment: Pattern matching to extract propeties should be discouraged since properties are just methods with void input, and invoking methods can cause side-effects.